# Django - how to order a sequence of videos within a topic?

Tags: mysql, django

I am putting together a video library in django.  So far I have a few courses, each subgrouped to a topic, then each topic has 10-20 videos each.

I would like to provide ordering for each grouping of videos within a topic.  So when a user goes through the lessons there is a specific sequence to the videos.

My challenge is how to store the ordering of videos in my database backend (mysql) and further how to look up and retrieve the order?  I also want to have (previous) and (next) links so a user can easily click through the sequence.

At first I was thinking I would just have a "sequence" int field on my video model, then look that up and simply find the next or previous one.  However, what if a number is skipped when entering the sequence?  I'd like to enforce the numbering in each sequence too.

Here's some code so far:

```
class Video(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    topic = models.ForeignKey('VideoTopic')
    sequence = models.IntegerField(default=1, null=True, help_text="(Sequence within the topic)")

class VideoTopic(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    course = models.ForeignKey('course.Course')
```

While this somewhat fulfills the base requirements of sequencing, I don't see how to enforce the ordering, and I'm also having difficulty looking up my previous/next videos.

I'm thinking I need to store sequence in a separate table, but I can't quite conceive how this should be done.  Something like:

```
class VideoSequence(models.Model)
    topic = models.ForeignKey('VideoTopic')
    sequence = models.IntegerField()
    video = models.ForeignKey('Video')
```

If I use the above separate table, how can I go about looking up the sequence in django?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SIMPLE ANSWER:**

https://github.com/iambrandontaylor/django-admin-sortable

**LESS SIMPLE ANSWER:**

The standard way to do this is what you already have, with a numeric ordering field.  If you want to enforce consecutive order indices you could use a signal to 'reindex' the sequences each time one is changed.

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

def update_sequence(sender, instance=False, created, **kwargs):
    qs = self.topic.video_set.all().order_by('sequence')
        counter = 1
        for video in qs:
            video.sequence = counter
            video.save()
            counter += 1

post_save.connect(update_sequence, sender=Video)
```

Then to get the next/previous item in the sequence:

models.py:

```
class Video(models.Model):
    ....
    class Meta:
        order_by = 'sequence'

    def get_next(self):
        return self.__class__.filter(sequence__gt=self.sequence)[0]

    def get_prev(self):
        return self.__class__.filter(sequence__lt=self.sequence)[-1]
```

---

Comment: I love the update_sequence function - this all seems just right for my needs at the moment. Thanks!